# How to collapse or expand source code in vim?

Tags: vim, source-code

How to collapse or expand source code in vim on HTML, PHP, etc?

EDIT: I know the basic folding command but what I need is something much more advance and intelligent such as in Visual Studio. I think it could not help without some really good plugin.

Comment: For reference, the basic folding commands in vim are `zf{motion}` to create a fold, `zo` to open a fold, and `zc` to close a fold.

Answer (score 3):

`:help foldcolumn` will tell you about how to create a small area left of the text that contains some controls to fold and unfold.

read about `:help foldmethod` about how to create folds automatically, eg. `:set foldmethod=syntax`.